# Click a submit type input when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, submit

How to click an input with the type submit when a button was clicked?

```
    $(document).on('click', 'button.editManufacturer', function(event) { 
        event.preventDefault(); 
        $(".editManufacturerSubmit").click();
    });
```

The snippet above is the code i have so far, but it doesn't work?

Thank you!

**===== EDIT =====**

Let me explain my problem a little bit more exactly!

I've a lot of forms that i want to submit via only one button.

The following things I have tried before:

```
    $("button.editManufacturer").click( function() {
        $('form.editManufacturer').submit();
    });
```

=========================================================================

"form" attribute at the button / input

=========================================================================

and some other things, were i havent the snippets anymore

=========================================================================

NOTE: only the last form is getting submitted

Comment: add html mark up as well

Comment: As SO guide states "provide code people can use to reproduce the problem"

Answer (score 0):

**You can Try this**

```
$('button.editManufacturer').on('click', function(event) { 

    $(".editManufacturerSubmit").trigger("click");
});
```

I am Hopeful it will work for you.

Comment: Did you add the jquery link files in your page?

**<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>**

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work as it is, you may have to provide more code which replicates the problem.

```js
$(document).on('click', 'button.editManufacturer', function(event) { 
  event.preventDefault(); 
  $(".editManufacturerSubmit").click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="https://httpbin.org/post" method="post">
  <button class="editManufacturer" >button</button>
  <input type="submit" class="editManufacturerSubmit" value="get" onClick="alert('hi')"/>
</form>
```

Comment: but somehow it does not submit the form?

Comment: It does submit the form, see update snippet (using httpbin to test it, see here https://httpbin.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("form").submit(function(event) { 
   event.preventDefault(); 
});
```

});

Comment: That's not what I am looking for, sorry - but thank you for your answer

Comment: add the html snippet , let me check

Comment: Try This  $("button.editManufacturer").click( function() {
   $("form.editManufacturer").each(function(){
    $(this).submit();  
  });
});

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is this

```
$('.editManufacturer').click(function(){
  $('form').submit();
});
```

Comment: i've tried this before!

let me explain - i have many forms on one page, and i want them to submit via one button. but nothing works? i also tried to add the "form" attribute to the input / button and tried a lot of js variations, but nothing seems to work :(

Comment: you mean one button for all forms? if so why don't you put it in one form?

Comment: beacause the forms are saving / updating different documents to one collection in mongodb :/